# trying to build an array of objects, but getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to build an array of objects, but getting a nullpointer exception when trying to set them.

Why when it gets to the first cars[i], it throws the exception?

Here is the code:
Example 1: http://pastebin.com/4h4W3770
Example 2: http://pastebin.com/4GL4FhrW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an array object, all its element are initialized to `null` (if array contains subclass of `java.lang.Object`). You need to instantiate each element before accessing any property . You are trying to set `Cars` property without instantiating it in the code below which is causing `NullPointerException`:

```
car[i].setPlate(info[0]);
```

Before doing this you need to initialize an instance of Car like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sCurrentLine;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cars.txt"))) {
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] info = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    car[i] = new Cars();   //instantiate Cars object or next statement will throw NPE
                    car[i].setPlate(info[0]);
                    car[i].setLocation(Integer.parseInt(info[1]));
                    car[i].setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(info[2]));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setter methods dont get any input / parameters, so they dont know what they should set:

```
public void setSpeed() {
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

Change to:

```
public void setSpeed(Integer speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I used an old link in the question, I updated it and already fixed this. Any idea still?

Comment: Ah, your examples make more sense now. Think sud29 has the correct answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple problem. you have never initialised `car[i]`. `car[i]` is `null` and when you try any operation to a variable that is `null` you get a `NullPointerException`.

So the solution is to initialise `car[i]` As shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   car[i] = new Cars(); //intialise the car.
   car[i].setPlate(info[0]);
   car[i].setLocation(Integer.parseInt(info[1]));
   car[i].setSpeed(Integer.parseInt(info[2]));
}
```

This I think will solve your problem.